# Google Webmasters API for Java returns empty site list

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-java-client, google-search-console

I have written a simple site list query code which uses Oauth with **service account** based on Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). The authentication key file (.p12) being used is valid as well as the account.

The problem is that sites list method returns an empty list.

```
service.sites().list().execute();
```

Also if I explicitly try to get sitemaps of a validated site, by calling

```
service.sitemaps().list("my.sample.site.com").execute();
```

I got a 403 Forbidden - "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'sample.site.com'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999." error from the API.

According to my debugging, the API perfectly loads the key file (.p12) and manages the access tokens etc. with no problems.

Nevertheless there might be a problem with my **service account** authentication.

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-webmasters</artifactId>
  <version>v3-rev6-1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Sample code:**

```
package webmastertools;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.webmasters.Webmasters;
import com.google.api.services.webmasters.WebmastersScopes;
import com.google.api.services.webmasters.model.SitesListResponse;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;

public class GoogleWebmastersClient {

    static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(GoogleWebmastersClient.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            String emailAddress = "012345789@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            String applicationName = "Sitemap Generator";

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("/path/to/auth.p12"))
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singletonList(WebmastersScopes.WEBMASTERS))
                    .build();

            Webmasters service = new Webmasters.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(applicationName)
                    .build();

            SitesListResponse siteList = service.sites().list().execute();

            if (siteList.isEmpty()) {
                logger.info("Site list is empty!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Before I dig in, the "Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account" section doesn't apply to your case, does it? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority (disclosure: i work with the Search Console (former Webmaster Tools ) team at Google)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some debugging of Google's Oauth authentication code, a colleague of mine discovered that there was nothing wrong with my code but there is a certain procedure that should be followed at Google Webmasters Console which nowhere to mentioned by the way:

- You have to give "full" permission to your service account email address for each of your domains. If you gave the "ownership" before, you have to revoke that ownership (because you can not modify the permission if you give ownership before giving permission).
- You have to give ownership to your service account email address.

If you do this in the wrong order; your site will not be listed in sitemaps list and even if you explicitly try to get sitemaps of your site by it's address you will get an authentication error.

**You have to give permissions and ownerships for each domain you would like to access (even just for getting their names).**

**There is no single top level access control for all your sites.**

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this info. I was missing this piece of the puzzle and could not find it anywhere. Now, we are finally up and running with our Search Console data retrieval :-)

Comment: @Oliver you are very welcome. :) It is nice to see someone really benefitted from my experience. It is also unfortunate that this bug still hasn't been fixed in two years.

Comment: This drove me nuts! Thank you! To be clear, in the Search Console, click the settings and choose Users and Property Owners. If you've added your Service Account as an owner already (click Manage property owners), Unverify it. Go back, and choose Users and Property Owners again, and click the ADD A NEW USER button. Enter the Service Account's email address here and select Full from the Permission dropdown. I was able to retrieve the sitemap listing without making the Service Account an Owner. I may still be forced to make it an Owner as I explore other functionality.

Comment: Thanks, @DJGrossman, for your detailed comment. I was just about to verify the necessity of making the service account an owner myself, but now I don't have to :-)

Comment: I've written up a detailed how-to blog post on connecting to the Search Console via Google API: http://shades-of-orange.com/post/How-to-Retrieve-Your-Google-Search-Console-Data-via-API. Thanks for all of your input and insight!

Comment: Thank you! Still relevant in Aug. 2019

Comment: Thanks for this post! And, still relevant in 2020. I am using this to submit sitemaps and it needed owner permissions, didn't work with Full permissions